# C allocate 2D array different sizes

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have this:

```
uint64_t **array;
int a;

if((array = malloc(8 * 25)) == NULL){
    errx(1, "malloc");
}

for(a = 0; a < 25; a++){
    if((array[a] = malloc(8 * (1 << a))) == NULL){
        errx(1, "malloc 1");
    }   
}
```

In the worst scenario I'll use 2^a bits, it means, I don't always need to use uint64_t for this, and uint even. My idea is allocate just 1 byte for a < 8, 2 bytes for a < 16 and a >=8  and this way to 8 bytes (uint64_t).

Is possible to do that? How I can do that using just my variable array?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: Are you trying to allocate a bit array (to store individual bits) or are you just concerned about over allocation?

Comment: @Frederico note in the worst case you are using `2^(a+3)` bytes and not `2^a` bits malloc allocates in bytes not bits so this would not work as you expect

Comment: @LiraNuna just concerned about over allocation

Comment: `(8*(1<<a))=> 2^a *8 => 2^(a+3)` bytes note malloc allocates in bytes

Comment: Unless you are on a very limited embedded system saving those few bytes here and there won't give you anything, your by far best option would be to not worry about it and just use a type big enough, like `uint64_t`. The overhead added by malloc will probably "waste" much more memory than the few bytes overallocation, so if you really need to save every byte, start by allocating all the data in one big block.

Comment: @sth I'm will populate this array with GBs of data. The bytes saved for 8 bits long numbers are ridiculous, but at 30 bits, I'll have 2^30 numbers of 32 bits, instead of 64 bits, this is a lot of memory saved!

Answer (score 0):

This probably should've been a comment (or 3), but...

You need to start by figuring out exactly how many bytes you will need (and for what, though I assume you have that part covered.)

What is 25? Why are you allocating memory for 25 different arrays of size 8, 16, 32 ... 2^27? This may be sample code, but we're still thrown off by a magic number: 25. We could've used the name of the constant (or the preprocessor macro).

8 is another magic number and it is also problematic. `sizeof(*array)` is not guaranteed to be 8.

I'm also a bit confused by your idea. Your current code allocates 1024 bytes for a=7. How will a single byte be enough to store whatever you saw a need to allocate 1024 bytes for in your prototype?